# SQL - Search 'Address' Where Contains string parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which locates the specific address.

**Fields**

- City
- Province
- Zip code

**Records**

- City : Manila, Makati, Cebu City, Kawit
- Province : NCR, NCR, CEBU, CAVITE
- Zip Code: 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444

My parameter only accepts 1 full string

Sample:

```
Declare @param as nvarchar (50)
SET @param = 'Man NC'
--query where condition like @param
```

The result should be **Manila, NCR 111**. I already tried this query. But obviously not correct because parameter contains city and province.

```
SELECT c.CityName, p.ProvinceName, c.Zipcode 
FROM City c (NOLOCK)
JOIN Province p (NOLOCK) ON c.ProvinceCode = p.ProvinceCode
WHERE c.CityName like '%' + @param + '%' 
OR p.ProvinceName like '%' + @param + '%' 
OR (c.CityName + ' ' + p.ProvinceName) like '%' + @param + '%'
```

I've seen some post here in stackoverflow suggesting using FULL-TEXT SEARCH. But how to do this without using the said function?

Comment: This looks a lot like SQL Server code, which unfortunately has almost no regex search support natively.  So, something like full text search, or a custom UDF would be your only option to get close to the functionality you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you point me to a sample custom UDF.

Comment: Just search SO for a while, and you should find something.

Comment: Why should the result be what you say? What's the logic behind braking down the parameter into the different columns? You are storing the address correctly, why on earth aren't you using the same for the parameters?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Im not inserting the records. The records are fixed and the UI has 1 search bar. Some users wants to just type the keywords for city province or zipcode and the result should be the closest records that has those keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to concatenate your fields before you like them.  You're also allowed to edit your like string:

```
SELECT c.CityName, p.ProvinceName, c.Zipcode 
FROM City c (NOLOCK)
JOIN Province p (NOLOCK) ON c.ProvinceCode = p.ProvinceCode
WHERE CONCAT(c.CityName, ",", p.ProvinceName) like CONCAT('%', REPLACE(@param, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Here I CONCAT the city and the province together and I turn your "Man NC" into "%Man%NC%" which will find the concatenated value

If you will feed queries in like "NC Man" you could simply have an OR with a CONCAT that concatenates the province  then city. You could get a lot more involved, splitting the value etc; it really depends on what you specify (and you haven't put a lot of spec into your question)

If you're going to be doing a lot of queries, it would be better to nail down the variations of @param and set some rules so that things can be better indexed. An example rule might be: @param must be a single word or two words, and the words must represent the start of a city name or a province name or a city name and a province name.

With rules like that you can split on space, CONCAT a % onto just the end of the words, and search the columns appropriately- possibly with a union rather than an or (can be faster)

Edit: version without CONCAT function

```
WHERE (c.CityName + "," + p.ProvinceName) like ('%' + REPLACE(@param, ' ', '%') + '%')
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.


I have this result when trying your query.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Wow, it's 11 years old! I think you sql server is in dire need of an upgrade :) Ok, there isn't anything special about CONCAT that you can't do with +, just change `CONCAT(a,b,c)` to `a+b+c` / I just prefer concat because if any value is null it is treated as '' rather than making the whole concatenation string null

Comment: The most important thing about my post is to replace the space in Man NC with a % so that the LIKE still works

Comment: LOL! Yup our servers are a bit old. This 2008 server is the last one left and maintaining lots of systems and databases. Btw, your code works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want.

```
Declare @city table (city varchar(50))

insert into @city values ('Manila'),('Makati'),('Cebu City'),('Kawit')

Declare @province table (Province varchar(50),zip int)

insert into @province values ('NCR',1111),('NCR',2222),('CEBU',3333),('CAVITE','4444')

select top 1 city + ', ' + Province + cast(zip as varchar) as name from @city c cross join @province d  where city like 'Man%' and Province like 'NC%'
```